# clear singleton data and everything when user logout

Tags: swift, singleton

I have an application that when user login I get data from the server with singleton class but the problem is when user logout(exit from login not exit from application) I can't renew singleton class, is there a way that when user log out clear all data and class?
My singleton class is as follows

```
    import Foundation
    class GetloginData{

        static let instance = GetloginData()
        private let personData : PersonData = generateLoginData()

        func getLoginData () -> PersonData {
            return personData
        }
    }
 func generateLoginData() -> PersonData {

       name = service.getname
balance = service.balance
 return  PersonData(name: name, balance: balance)

    }
```

service is soap webservice

Comment: you can call or notify at time logout from application. so log out time data is cleared.

and where to store data, in user defaults?

Comment: Show us the singleton class code, otherwise your question is too vague for being able to help you properly

Comment: and explain what you mean by "can't renew" unless the code explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can simply change the personData to optional and add a method to resetLoginData**

```
import Foundation

class GetloginData {
        static let instance = GetloginData()
        private var personData : PersonData? = generateLoginData()

        func getLoginData () -> PersonData? {
            return personData
        }

        func resetLoginData() {
            personData = nil
        }
    }
```

**And on your logout button put it like**

```
GetloginData.instance.resetLoginData()
```

Also, use guard else to check for the logged in or not and handle it accordingly.

```
guard let loggedInPerson = GetloginData.instance.getLoginData() else {
  // HANDLE CODE TO RETURN TO LOGIN SCREEN.
  return
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this code was correct but when I call GetloginData.instance.getLoginData() again return nil

Comment: can you please post code for, what you are doing in generateLoginData() function.

Comment: update your function to return optional PersonData like this func generateLoginData() -> PersonData? and then try to print the print(name)  and print(balance) to see if there is value.